# Is there a standard mode for .ini files?

Tags: major-mode, syntax-highlighting

After looking for a mode for `.ini` files, I found `ini-mode` via MELPA, but upon installing it in Emacs 26, there was a message about it being an obsolete mode. What are the alternatives?  In my limited testing, `conf-mode` seems to work for `.ini`-style files too, but I'm wondering whether there are other solutions that are specifically about `.ini` files. In terms of functionality, I'm primarily looking for syntax highlighting and indentation.

Comment: Primarily opinion-based, and unclear. Should be closed. Define "modern". Define "better". What syntax highlighting and indentation? Etc.

Comment: Edited in an effort to make it more objective.

Comment: @mhucka, ini-mode should work with Emacs 26. Which warning message did you get?

Answer (score 9):

`conf-mode.el` says:

> This mode is designed to edit many similar varieties of Conf/Ini files and
>   Java properties.  It started out from Aurélien Tisné's `ini-mode`.
>   `conf-space-keywords` were inspired by Robert Fitzgerald's `any-ini-mode`.

So `conf-mode` seems to be what you're looking for (and comes with Emacs).

Comment: The help for the `conf-mode` function (at least in Emacs 26.3) does not mention ini files. I guess I should have looked in the source file!